# d3 area graph going out of bounds

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am struggling to keep the area graph inbounds for a particular set of data. I am not able to figure out what exactly is making it go out of range

```
var  xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([0, numberOfDays + 1]),
          yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([_.min(areaData), _.max(areaData)]);
```

js fiddle here 
https://jsfiddle.net/sahils/o7df3tyn/20/

Comment: Your css on the `svg` tag is quite strange: `style="position: absolute;left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%);"`; what were you intending that to do?

Comment: oh that was just for the alignment of the graph in my page. Anyway that doesnt matter . I have removed that from the fiddle.   My question was regarding the range of the graph and how it is going out of the range. https://jsfiddle.net/sahils/o7df3tyn/21/

Answer (score 0):

Its due to you setting them exactly so these lines :

```
<svg id="visualisation" width="1200" height="400"></svg>
```

And

```
 WIDTH = 1000,
 HEIGHT = 400,
```

Rather than this just use window size :

```
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
  vis = d3.select('#visualisation').attr('width', WIDTH).attr('height', HEIGHT)
```

And remove the styling from your html. Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/o7df3tyn/23/

Comment: Its still going out of bounds right . Have a look at the tallest peak